# rounding the corners of TextFormField - not just the border, the whole Text Box

Tags: flutter, dart

I have done some searching on this and everyone is telling how to set a rounded border. But in my case I have a background color for my text boxes that is different from the background of the app screen, that is what I am trying to round, the background color border.

Desired Look:
[image]

What it looks like now: [image]

from main.dart ThemData...

```
theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
          primaryColor: Color(0xFF623CEA),
          fontFamily: 'Manrope',
          inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black)
            ),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
            ),
            // border: InputBorder.none,
            labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
            iconColor: Colors.grey,
          )
      ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FormSample extends StatelessWidget {
  const FormSample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Sample Text field")),
      body: _body(),
    );
  }

  Widget _body() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding:  EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey.shade300, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
            child: TextField(
              textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person_outline),
                border: InputBorder.none,
                hintText: "Full name",
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74159223/textformfield-active-colors-and-with-content-color

Answer (score 1):

Round the edges, but hide the width of the edge. Something like this.

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('Demo'),
  ),
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: Theme(
    data: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: const Color(0xFF623CEA),
        fontFamily: 'Manrope',
        inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.4),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
            borderSide:
                const BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent, width: 0),
          ),
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
            borderSide:
                const BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent, width: 0),
          ),
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
            borderSide:
                const BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent, width: 0),
          ),
          labelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.25)),
          iconColor: Colors.grey,
        )),
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: const [
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'TextField', prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person)),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: This did not work for me